# OS Installation via Mirror

Tags: system-installation, mirrors, kickstart

I am trying to do fresh machine installation via Kickstart over HTTP. During the installation the installer failed to download from the mirror on looking at the installer logs I could notice errors related to key verification.

How do we import the keys via kickstart or skip validation while kickstart installation any pointers?

Errors:

```
gpgv: Can't check signature: public key not found 
error: Bad signature on /tmp/net-retrivever-5641-Release
```

Ideally the file `/tmp/net-retrivever-5641-Release` is downloaded from the internal mirror site.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by adding the key which was used to sign the local mirror repository to /usr/share/keyrings in the ram image which was used for booting the machine for pxe installations